# ag-grid column menu reset columns event?

Tags: ag-grid

Does ag-grid have a grid event that corresponds to to the "Reset Columns" item that is at the bottom of each column menu?

I need to do some special processing on "Reset Columns", and different handling of column "move", "resize", (etc.).  I setup an event handler for the "columnEverythingChanged" event and a different event handler for "columnMoved" (etc.).  I found that:

1) When no changes have been made to any column and I press "Reset Columns", "columnEverythingChanged" gets called.  Fine.
2) When one or more columns have been changed and I press "Reset Columns", both "columnEverythingChanged" AND "columnMoved" (or other) get called.

My problem: in case (2), my "columnMoved" logic should not run.

A secondary problem: "columnEverythingChanged" also gets called at application startup.  Not a big deal, but I had to hack around it.

Comment: Did you figure out a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

This was so long ago, I don't remember the details.  But in my code, I see that I use the columnMoved, columnResized, columnVisible, filterChanged, and sortChanged events. I run the same function on all of these events. That function debounces the event before doing my special processing.

Answer (score 0):

you can use GlobalListener to work with multiple events without issue

```
gridOption.api.addGlobalListener(GlobalListenerSaveColumnState);

function GlobalListenerSaveColumnState(type, event) {
    if (type == "columnVisible" || type == "columnResized"|| type == "columnMoved"|| type == "columnPinned" || type == "dragStopped") {
        UpdateGridDefaultsIntoDb(event);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by 'overriding' the default `getMainMenuItems` function, which basically creates that "hamburger" icon, and reveals the options inside the Main Menu.  When overriden, you can supply the list of items you want to include, and you can give it your own function you want to run when "Reset Columns" is clicked.

```
this.gridOptions = {
    viewportDatasource: {
        init: this.init,
        setViewportRange: this.setViewportRange,
    },
    rowModelType: 'viewport',
    sideBar: localStorage.getItem('test_pivot') == 'true' ? 'columns' : '',
    suppressRowClickSelection: false,
    suppressMultiSort: true,
    rowMultiSelectWithClick: true,
    rowSelection: 'multiple',
    getMainMenuItems: (params) => this.getMainMenuItems(params), // <- This piece right here
    getContextMenuItems: this.getContextMenuItems,
};
```

Later you define that `getMainMenuItems()`

```
getMainMenuItems(params) {
    params.defaultItems[params.defaultItems.length - 1] = {
        name: this.translate.instant('i18n.reset_columns'),
        action: () => {
            this.onResetColumnStateClick(null); // <- The custom functionality you want to execute when Reset Columns is clicked
        },
    };

    return params.defaultItems;
}
```

I believe their documentation has another example containing the `getMainMenuItems` function

https://ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/column-menu/

https://plnkr.co/edit/?open=main.js&preview